# Customize Java Tapestry @IncludeStylesheet annotation

Tags: java, annotations, stylesheet, tapestry

Using Tapestry 5, I'm looking at a (if possible) elegant way to customize the `@IncludeStylesheet` annotation in order to automatically add a version number to the style sheet file name.

For instance

```
  @IncludeStylesheet("context:/css/decoration.css")
```

would generate automatically the CSS inclusion with a `v`ersion number

```
  <link href="/css/decoration.css?v=12345" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Adding a new annotation, like `@IncludeStylesheetVersion` was my initial idea.
Looking at the Tapestry code, it looks like I'm ahead of some code copy / refactoring, with new implementations of `RenderSupport` and `DocumentLinker` (among others).

Would there be a simpler way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not have to do that at all: Asset versioning is built into Tapestry. The default behaviour, according to the [docs](http://tapestry.apache.org/assets.html):

> Tapestry creates a new URL for assets
>   (whether context or classpath). The
>   URL is of the form `/assets/application
>   version number/folder/path`.
>
> - application version number: Defined by symbol `tapestry.application-version`, the default value is a random hex number.

If you just need to make sure clients will see changed stylesheets after an update and you don't restart your app all the time, the default behavior (random hex number) should do just fine.

*Edit based on comment:* This is also [available in 5.1](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.1/guide/assets.html):

> - app/app-version (for assets obtained    at or beneath the
>     application    package)
> - classpath/app-version (for    assets obtained from any otherwise
>     unmapped package)
>
> Where version is the Tapestry framework version, and app-version is the application version (which will be a random string if not explicitly configured).

Just check the URLs Tapestry generates for your CSS files, they should look like this: `http://myserver.com/assets/ctx/942f15f778dca26c/css/styles.css`

Comment: @Henning Thanks - but I'm afraid the auto versioning is not implemented in versions 5.0.1/5.1

Comment: @Henning Would you know by chance if the upgrade from 5.0.18 to 5.2.x is flawlessly? (besides the deprecations)

Comment: @ring0 I haven't yet used 5.2, as it was only released lately. I have, however, updated apps written for 5.0 to 5.1, which worked almost flawlessly.

Comment: @Henning Would you mind to elaborate a little on the merits of the migration - did you notice performance improvements (features changes must also have been a +)

Comment: @ring0 I can't say if it's much faster as none of my apps are under much stress, and 5.0 was pretty fast to begin with. The JS combining and GZIP compression are very welcome additions, though.

Comment: @Henning Looking at the link your provided, there is a big change between 5.1 and 5.2: an instance per locale is created (no more pages pool) and objects have to be thread-safe. Pretty huge change that vetoes a quick update... Thanks a lot for all your comments.

Comment: @ring0: You're welcome. As I said, I have never used 5.2, I was referring to the upgrade to 5.1.

Comment: @Henning Quick update: in the process of 5.1.0.5 mig, and the CSS files get a version number, as expected. Great!

Comment: 5.2 is worth updating to. a few tidy-ups and performance improvements. the only non-backwards compatibility i found was to do with configuring translators in your module. if you don't do this, i think it will be seamless.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the effort you'd put into upgrading to 5.3 will probably be better spent than trying to create an annotation to mimic the built in functionality of current versions.  I think you'll find the upgrade process pretty painless--particularly if you have good integration testing in place.